# blender does not start after kernel update despite reinstall

Tags: kernel, libraries, blender

Hi I recently updated my ubuntu 12.04.3 installation with the new kernel 3.8.0.30
After that blender did not start any more with the message that:

```
/usr/lib/blender/blender: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I downloaded blender from the blender website and unpacked it in a separate directory. There blender did start.

purging blender and reinstalling it did not help.

please advice

Comment: /usr/lib/blender -- an odd place to install binaries. The error says it can't find libavformat.so.55. `ldd /usr/lib/blender/blender` will list shared libs and paths it expects to find them.

Comment: I agree. the command $ whereis blender showed:
blender: /usr/bin/blender /usr/lib/blender /usr/bin/X11/blender /usr/share/blender /usr/share/man/man1/blender.1.gz
This happened by sudo apt-get install blender.
(ubuntu 12.04.3, kernel 3.8.0.30)

Comment: I tried to install blender on my 13.04 labtop and that worked ok. When diving deeper I checked with locate libavformat.so.55 the laptop came with a location in usr/lib/blender. That was missing in the 12.04.4 installation. A than tried to purge all blender related libraries and reinstall them. Does not work because I got the error message that blender needs certain libs which are not going to be installed. I installed them by hand and than blender got a little further but crashed to the command prompt. Please advice on how to reinstall the right libs.